# Unchecking all RadioButtons in a For Each Control loop

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I've got 7 `RadioButtons` on my form, 5 in one group, 2 in another. When they were in `GroupBoxes`, checking one of the `RadioButtons` didn't uncheck the other ones in the same `GroupBox`, for some reason - I think because the `AutoCheck` value was set to `False`, which it had to be because otherwise when the form loaded, one of the `RadioButtons` would be checked by default, and I don't want this to happen.

So, to uncheck the other `RadioButtons` within the same `GroupBox`, I'm trying to write a subroutine which is called, after setting the value to `True` in the `RadioButton_Click` event.

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
      If TypeOf c Is RadioButton Then
          If c.Name <> "rbtnAllSuppliers" AndAlso c.Name <> "rbtnIndividual" Then
              If c.Name <> rbtn.Name Then
                  For Each rbt As RadioButton In Me.Controls
                      If rbt.Name = c.Name Then
                          rbt.Checked = False
                      End If
                  Next
              End If
          End If
      End If
Next
```

This code moreorless works. For each control on the form, if it's a `RadioButton` which isn't called `rbtnAllSuppliers` or `rbtnIndividual` (The 2 seperate `RadioButtons`, and it's not the `RadioButton` that is being set to `True`, then set it to `False`.

The issue being, it is counting the 2 `Labels` as `RadioButtons`, or at least casting them to be so, so it errors when trying to set a ``Checked`value of the`Label`.

I then tried something similar

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If c.GetType Is GetType(RadioButton) Then
            If c.Name <> "rbtnAllSuppliers" AndAlso c.Name <> "rbtnIndividual" Then
                If c.Name <> rbtn.Name Then
                    AddHandler DirectCast(c, RadioButton).Checked, AddressOf c.
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

But I'm not sure what I would put for the `AddressOf` code? What would go in here as the delegate? If I put `AddressOf currentSubroutine()`, surely an infinite loop will be created?

Is there a way to uncheck all `RadioButtons` using a similar method that I'm not aware of?

What's the best way to go about achieving this?

Comment: Did you try `Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)` to avoid reaching any labels?

Comment: @AFriend Perfect! Seems to be working exactly as required so far, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)` you can avoid having to check the type inside your loop, and will ensure that every control is a `RadioButton`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the suggested approach, you can also specify which group you want to loop through the controls.

```
For Each RadioButtonItem In TargetGroupBox.Controls.OfType(Of Radiobutton)
    RadioButtonItem.Checked = False
Next
```